# Unable to convert BLOB to base64

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, blob, react-admin

I am trying to convert my uploaded image to a base64 before sending it to the backend for processing, and I am using `readAsDataUrl` for doing the same, but the result comes as null always,

convertToBase64 () --

```
    const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);
    
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = reject;
    });
```

Blob :

```
{
    "rawFile": {
        "path": "Logo.png"
    },
    "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/5ff2faa0-6f37-4c2e-906a-4c953d146efa",
    "title": "Logo.png"
}
```

I am passing this blob as a file parameter to my `convertToBase64` method, but `reader.result` is null always
While debugging I can see the promise being still pending and not resolved, could this be the reason it being null? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile.path); //path of the file

  reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
  reader.onerror = reject;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing in a blob as `file` then you can probably change `reader.readDataAsURL(file.rawFile)` to just `reader.readDataAsURL(file)`

This worked for me:

index.html

```
...
<body>
  <input type="file" id='file'/>
  <script src='./app.js'></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
const fileReader = document.getElementById('file')

const getBase64 = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader()

    console.log(file instanceof Blob) // Should be true

    fr.readAsDataURL(file)
    fr.onerror = reject
    fr.onload = function () {
      resolve(fr.result)
    }
  })
}

fileReader.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  getBase64(e.target.files[0]).then((res) => console.log(res) )
})
```